# RAILS How to give an argument to Model function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this function in my user.rb Model :

```
def change_key
  self.public_key = params[:public_key]
end
```

I want to call this function from a script on Views (new.html.erb) like this :

```
change_key(x);
```

and I want self.public_key to get the x value

The result I get is :

> undefined local variable or method `params' for

Any thoughts??

Comment: The way you described your problem doesn't make any sense. You defined function without any arguments yet you try to call it with one (`change_key(x)`). What is this `change_key` method?

Comment: Your method is in the model which has no access to `params` by default.  Also your method needs to be defined to take an argument if you intend to pass it one.

Comment: the change_key method changes the public_key attribute of every User created. That is the question, how can I pass an argument to a function of Model?

Comment: Not to mention that if you call this kind of method in view, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Take a look: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass an argument, you would do

```
def change_key(params)
  self.public_key = params[:public_key]
end
```

Which you could call as:

```
@model.change_key(x)
```

And, as long as `@model` has an attribute `public_key`, and `x` is something `hash`-like, then it should work.

Unless, of course, you expect `@model.public_key` to be persisted. In which case, it would be something more like:

```
def change_key(params)
  self.public_key = params[:public_key]
  self.save
end
```

Which is silly because you could do that in one shot, like:

```
def change_key(params)
  self.update(public_key: params[:public_key])
end
```

But, why declare a `change_key` method at all when you can simply do:

```
@model.update(public_key: params[:public_key])
```

Which, of course, you *definitely* do not want to do in a `view` because (IMO) your `view`s should *never* be making changes to your models in your views. Doing so requires that your `view` layer requires intimate knowledge of your `model` layer - which makes your application brittle.

Comment: I got a 'Users' table on my database ( I use devise). A user has some attributes and public_key is on of them (and is just a string). I produce a public key inside a script on new.html.erb and I want to save it on database for each user. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this. You could do it either in the `new` or `create` actions of your `UsersController`. Or, you could do it in your `User` model using a `call_back` either during `initialize` or `save`. Any of these has pros and cons.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answers.So inside the new function of the controller I should change the attribute? How would I pass the variable which is on the script to the function of the controller?

Comment: Welp. I don't know when the first time is that you need to access the `public_key`. My tendency would be to set the attribute in the `create` action, but you *could* do it in the `new` action. I also don't know what your script looks like, but the logic for creating the `public_key` probably belongs in the controller or in a service.

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs to expect an argument:

```
def change_key(arg)
  self.public_key = arg
end
```

However since this is a model method, it should not be called directly in the view as this is not MVC.  But if you wanted to use it in a controller action, that might work.  You'd need to define a controller action and maybe use javascript to make an ajax request to your controller action, where it could then operate on your model.

Comment: I get "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)" when I try this

Comment: `x` needs to be defined before you pass it to a method. so first try `x = 'foo'` then call the method with x or just do `change_key('foo')`